# Launch Safari from IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, safari

I understand I can launch Safari from IOS using the following line.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

How can I launch Safari without opening any given URL? In other words how to mimic the user manually launching Safari?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"]];`